# Xamarin Auth package Works in the Xamarin tvos?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on Xamarin tv iOS. Please let me know Xamarin Auth working on the Xamarin tv iOS ?
I am trying the OAuth2Authenticator.GetUI() in the Login but It needs the reference of the Xamarin.iOS DLL

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the project's [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth) page, it does not mention support for TVOS